# Update Class of Iframe by Rich Text Editor

Tags: richtext-editor

I have one form URL which I rendering using `Iframe in Sitecore Rich Text Editor` in 'src' attribute as below:

[image]

There is one CTA button form that overlapping some of the form text. So to come out that issue I am to update a class attribute in Iframe. example: add `Padding-bottom:25px` attribute to `Class name : Form-Disclaimer`.

As we can do it in HTML file using JSS as below:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6494721/override-body-style-for-content-in-an-iframe

Can I do it in Rich Text Editor or how can I achieve this?

Comment: Just modify the html via the rich text editor? or am I missing something here?

Comment: @RichardSeal Yes, I want to modify the Iframe HTML tag class via Sitecore RTE. Any hacks can we do ?

Comment: The HTML tag inside the iframe? That is not possible, the iframe is a linked document, you need to modify the original page that is linked, you can't set that from the iframe element itself.

Answer (score 3):

#### The Below Answer, while answering the main question, is NOT recommended!

The short answer here is that OOTB no, you cannot and should not do this via the RichTextEditor. To be able to modify html/css in the target of an IFrame, first the page inside the IFrame must be on the same domain as your current page, and then you would need JavaScript to modify it. If the target page is from a different domain, then you have no options, you just can't change it.

For security reasons, the RichTextEditor strips out any JavaScript entered. You *can* disable that by changing this setting:

```
<!-- HTML EDITOR REMOVE SCRIPTS
If true, the rich text editor removes script tags and inline scripts from RTE field     
values before saving. Setting the value to true reduces the potential for cross-site 
scripting and other script-related issues.
Default value: true
-->
<setting name="HtmlEditor.RemoveScripts" value="true" />
```

But I would not recommend that, as it would disable it for *all* RichTextEditors in your site.

If you do it, then you could use JavaScript similar to this to modify the target html/css:

```
var iframe = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0];
iframe.addEventListener("load", function() {
    window.frames[0].document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#ccc";
});
```

Do this at your own risk!